# How to get the url params in this case

Tags: angular

I'm on angular 7 , i want to capture the token param from this URL :
http://localhost:4200/createpassword/token=xxxxxxxx

on my routing path i have added :
path: 'createpassword/:token'

the issue is the browser redirect to http://localhost:4200/createpassword/token when adding the xxxxxxxx parameter

Comment: You either need to change your path to `createpassword/token/:token` or to `createpassword?token=xxxx` and get them from `ActivatedRoute`

Comment: Harun, i'm getting the url from an API so i can't change the format to createpassword?token=xxxx, must be in this format http://localhost:4200/createpassword/token=xxxxxxxx

Comment: I suggest you find a way to modify the API response somehow because this is not even a valid URL which is why it is being auto-converted to a recognized URL. I'm sure it should be possible to ask for the API to be changed especially when there's such a clear problem with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed on server side, the avoide the ivalid URL.

Answer (score 0):

Your url is incorrect, it should look like this:

http://localhost:4200/createpassword/token/xxxxxxxx

This is how the parameters url looks like in angular

You've commented that you're getting this url from an API, than all you need to do is to manipulate it before using it

```
this.apiService.getURL().subscribe(url => {
  // change the url before using it
});
```

Comment: Yes i agree, but in my case i'm getting this URL from an API, so im forced to use this url format http://localhost:4200/createpassword/token=xxxxxxxx

Comment: @nabilinfo As I said, this url is not working in angular. Why you're forced to use it? Can't you change it before using it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your url like this

1. Remove `token` parameter from the route: `path: 'createpassword'`
2. Get `ActivatedRoute` in your component: `constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute)`
3. Implement `OnInit` in your component and get the query parameters using the provided `route` - `queryParams` observable:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  token: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => this.token = params['token']);
  }
}
```

Here is a [StackBlitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nbs-angular-routing-question-mark-params)